# how to use grep to search for 2 or more parentheses and words capitalization

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to search for a couple of strings in a path that includes about 80 txt files.

I'm trying to search for !!, ??, ;, capitalization, and parentheses.
I'm also trying to search for if there are more than 4 words capitalized, but I just didn't know how to do that

Here is what I did:

```
grep -lr '!!\|??\|;\|(.*(' path
```

Can someone help me with it?

Here is a sample input:

file1.txt:

```
ryan went over there !!
```

file2.txt:

```
am I going there??
```

file3.txt:

```
how about I GO TO THE PARK TODAY and not TOMORROW
```

file4.txt:

```
This is (not) (valid)
```

file5.txt:

```
to go; or not to go
```

the output should be something like this:

```
path/file1.txt
path/file2.txt
path/file3.txt
path/file5.txt
```

Comment: please provide some sample input to make things easier to understand

Comment: this is a sample input, what about the desired output for this given input? [edit] and show what should be it. Also, it looks like a very small amount of sample input, hopefully it is enough to understand what you mean here.

Comment: In your sample input the parentheses are not adjacent.  Your grep string appears to be searching for multiple adjacent parentheses.

Comment: @fedorqui well, I didn't want to include ALL the files but something like this will be good for it. the output should only be the path of the files, which in this case, everything should be shown

Comment: @JohnGordon That's basically my question. I'm not really sure how to do that. I don't want the grep to search for something like this: (ryan) without another (ryan)

Comment: Why are you putting backslashes before the pipe symbols?  That will make grep search for actual pipe symbols, instead of interpreting it as an `OR` operation.

Comment: @JohnGordon I thought this is how you search for 2 different things with grep? so should I just get rid of the backslashes?

Comment: This will find lines containing two left-parentheses: `'(.*('`

Comment: @JohnGordon no, OP is right. `\|` is the way to say OR in grep. You can also say `grep -E "A|B"`.

Comment: @rullzing regarding `!!` and `??` you have it. The point here is on how to find files that contain more than one block of `(` + text + `)`, right?

Comment: @fedorqui Yes, which John gave me the answer for. I am also trying to find a way to search for 4 words capitalized

Comment: You should stick to one single problem. Otherwise, this is undoable. [edit] your question to show something more clear, remove what you already know how to do and ask just one thing. If you have more questions, ask more different questions.

Comment: ` grep -lr '!!\|??\|;\|({2,3,4}' *` worked for me finding files 1, 2, and 3 without finding 4.  There is a problem with your test set or you are not asking the right question.  If you use `-o` it will show that file3 does not test double `(` but rather `;`

Comment: @Matt good catch. I fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
grep -Er '\?\?|\!\!|\(.+\).+\(.+\)|([A-Z]+\b.){4,}|\;' /path/to/files/*.txt
```

Output:

```
./1.txt:ryan went over there !!
./2.txt:am I going there??
./3.txt:how about I GO TO THE PARK TODAY and not TOMORROW
./4.txt:This is (not) (valid)
./5.txt:to go; or not to go
```

`grep -Elr` will output:

```
./1.txt
./2.txt
./3.txt
./4.txt
./5.txt
```

The regex searches for:

1. **??**
2. **!!**
3. **()** used at least twice on a line
4. Four or more **capitalized words** on a line
5. **;**

Comment: usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
it didn't work  with me

Comment: Does replacing `-P` with `-E` help?

Comment: No, because you have used nongreedy quantifiers, which are a Perl extension.

Comment: @triplee Of course I did. But simply replacing `-P` with `-E` worked for the sample input files above on my Debian box. Same matches returned.

Comment: Good for you, but that is just one of several possible undefined behaviors.

Comment: @tripleee Just wanted to get OP's feedback before I did it, but now have updated the answer.

Comment: This looks very good, but I'm still confused about how exactly should I use the regex because I'm not so familiar with it. I tried to do it this way: grep -lr '!!\|??\|;\|(.*(\|b[A-Z]{4,}' but I didn't get what I wanted to get for some reason. Is my way of doing it incorrect?

Comment: @rullzing I believe you need the `-E` option for `{4,}` to work. But turning it on also requires escaping some characters with backslashes, like in my answer.

Comment: @rullzing You're welcome, please try my updated regex, I corrected the "four or more capitalized words on a line" part. I created two test files (one with 5 capitalized words, one with 3), and now only the first one is matched.

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is off. In modern `grep`, you need to backslash the braces, just like you backslash the vertical bar for alternation. More conveniently, you might want to switch to `grep -E` for backslashless syntax; but then you will need `\(` to match a literal opening parenthesis.

But either way, inside the braces, there can only be a maximum of two numbers: the lower and the upper bound for  he number of repetitions.

However, in this case, because there is no limiting context, `\({2)` will match the first two of an arbitrarily large number of opening parentheses. In other words, `\({2,4}` will not fail to match if there are more than four parens (though the actual match will end after four, as you will be able to see e.g. with `grep -o`). If you need to limit to no longer than four, you will need to supply some sort of trailing context, such as `($|[^(])`.

To find a line containing more than one but less than five nonadjacent opening parens, try something like

```
^[^(]*(\([^(]*){2,4}$
```

Comment: but wouldn't ({2} find something like ((r) but not (r) (r) ? I think (.*( is sufficient.

Comment: No, this is simply searching for literal ad]acent left parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -lr '!!\|??\|;\|(.*(' path
```

is what you want. `(.*(` will match a line containing (at least) two open parentheses with arbitrary text in between.

For readability, you might try

```
grep -lr -e '!!' -e '??' -e ';' -e '(.*(' path
```